# NTFS - fastest way to find file by creation/modification date

Tags: windows, winapi, ntfs

Given:

- NTFS volume
- folder path
- some date time value - lets call it $date

What is the fastest way to search for all files with

```
("last modification date" > $date) or ("creation date" > $date)
```

Simply I want to search for all added or modified files.

For performance reasons I don't want to do recursive crawl of all subfolders and read every file attributes.
For technical reasons (i.e. UAC, NTFS documentation) I would like to avoid parsing \\.\$mft file

Is there some Windows API that will allow me to do search in that way?

**Edit:** One more constraint:
 For maintenance reasons I don't want to be dependant on indexing service.

Comment: Seems to me that your constraints have eliminated all avenues.

Comment: If you don't want to use an indexing service, and you don't want to read the MFT, and you don't want to recursively crawl, what other option is there?

Comment: @Luke Seems like I'm asking for some Win32 API similiar to FindFirstFile that allows me to filter by creation/modification date.

Comment: As far as I know that functionality is not supported at the file system level, so you don't really have any other options.

Answer (score 1):

I can say with certainty that there is no other realistic option given the problem as stated.  FindFirst et al do not have a filtering mechanism.  If you were keeping up with the USN journal, there might be some leeway, but otherwise, no.

Answer (score 0):

If the windows indexing service is turned on, and the files you want are indexed, you quickly find your files using [the query api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff684394%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that I don't want to be dependant on indexing service. I'll update my question immediately.